# Solving a system of nonlinear coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I tried using `NDSolve` to solve the following system of equations:

```
t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], 
t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t],       
x[1] == 4, x[100] == 1
```

It's weird. The system tells me there is infinity at the boundary $t=1$, so I change the boundary from $t=1$ to $t=2$, and I get the same message again.

If I eliminate the nonlinear term `-5 t^2/x[t]^2`, the function can be solved analytically. So I do not know whether these equations are  well posed or not with such boundary conditions just for `x[t]`

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Please post the precise command you entered and quote the error message you got.

Comment: putting a side for a minute the 1/0 error, you need to have an initial/boundary condition for $y(t)$. Even though these are coupled, each derivative in the equations produces one constant of integration on its own. Are you sure you copied this problem correctly?

Comment: @Nasser, yes, I do need to specify a boundary condition for `y(t)` to satisfy my boundary conditions for `x(t)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted above, you need an initial condition for y. You can then solve the odes given `x[1] == 4` and `y[1] == y1` where `y1` is some real number. By solving the equations for different values of `y1`, you can see if there is a value such that `x[100] == 1`. In Version 9, it turns out the `ParametricNDSolve` will help you do this. Make `y1` a parameter:

```
{xsoln, ysoln} = {x, y} /. ParametricNDSolve[{
  t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], 
  t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t],
  x[1] == 4,
  y[1] == y1
}, {x, y}, {t, 1, 100}, {y1}]
```

Now locate a region where `y1` is likely to give the desired result:

```
Plot[xsoln[y1][100], {y1, 43.35, 43.5}, GridLines -> {{}, {1}}]
```

[image: likely region]

Next use `FindRoot` to get a precise value and call it `y1star`:

```
y1star = y1 /. FindRoot[xsoln[y1][100] == 1, {y1, 43.4}]
```

Finally, confirm that it produces the desired result

```
Plot[{xsoln[y1star][t], ysoln[y1star][t]}, {t, 1, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, All}, GridLines -> {{}, {1}}]
```

[image: desited solution]

Comment: thanks. I do not know whether my equations are well posed or not. you provide me a method to check whether my boundary conditions just for `x[t]` can work or not

Answer (score 4):

Although the solution by Nasser is entirely satisfactory, this alternative approach may be of interest.  Designate the two equations in the question as `eq1` and `eq2`, respectively.  Then, since `y` has no boundary conditions, eliminate it from the system.

```
Flatten@Solve[Subtract @@ eq1 + Subtract @@ eq2 == 0, y'[t]]
eq3 = Simplify[D[eq1, t] /. %]
(* {y'[t] -> (-5 t - x[t]^2 x'[t])/x[t]^2} *)
(* (5 t)/x[t]^2 + 3 x'[t] + t x''[t] == 0 *)
```

Then, solve the resulting equation for `x`, and from that result determine `y` as well (from `eq1`).

```
{sx, sxp} = NDSolveValue[{eq3, x[1] == 4, x[100] == 1}, {x, x'}, {t, 1, 100}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> x'[1] == 39.5}];
Plot[{sx[t], sx[t] + t sxp[t]}, {t, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {-20, All}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Nasser, you need to have an initial/boundary condition for y(t).
Here I assumed a random condition on y(t)

```
sol = NDSolve[{t x'[t] == -x[t] + y[t], t y'[t] == -5 t^2/x[t]^2 + x[t] - y[t], 
x[1] == 4, y[1] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 1, 2}]

Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"x[t]", "y[t]"}, Above]]
```

[image]